# Graphql don't map data from resolve function in to the server answer

Tags: graphql-js

I have express server with running GraphQL on it.

There is a schema with Foo type

```
FooType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Foo',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    surname: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
});

schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      foo: {
        type: FooType,
        resolve: () => fooResolver
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Resolver for `foo` returns object `{ name: 'bar', surname: 'boo' }`, but in response from graphQL server I got an object `{ name: 'bar', surname: null }`

The question is -

- Why could it be and how could it be possible?
- I thought GraphQL just maps the result object from resolver into
  response object, doesn't it?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you please show your `fooResolver` code? The problem might be there. Did you debug inside `FooType` to see received object returned from `fooResolver`?

Comment: Actually there is simple mongoose ```findOne``` operation and code is something like this ```FooModel.findOne({ bar: 'baz' })```